# Long stay visa and 90/180 rule

Tags: schengen

I got a short stay tourist visa for France from 24th Dec 2016 to 24th March 2017. I was in France for the entire duration of my visa, minus 2 days. Now I want to apply for a long-stay visitor visa starting on 23rd June. Does the 90/180 rule affect my long stay visa? In short, do I have to wait for my 180 days to be over before applying for a long stay visa?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'long stay visitor visa'? So called long stay visas (type D) are issued if you are intending to take up residency in a Schengen state and not for 'visitors'.

Comment: Long-stay visas are explicitly excluded from the 90/180 calculation.  But they are also generally off topic here; such questions should be posted on [expatriates.SE].

Comment: This _is_ Expatriates.